# Live Sass Compiler causing Extension Host crash after latest VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, sass, compiler-errors

I am trying to use sass styling and Live Sass Compiler extension, I recently installed it and now keep getting a **extension host terminated unexpectedly** error using VS Code.I have re-installed **Live Sass Compiler** several times as well as all my **Live** extensions and restarted my VS Code. [Live Extensions I've re-installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csMzx.png). I know its the Live Sass Compiler causing this issue, because once I uninstall, I don't see the error anymore, but I can't update any styling in my . scss files. Everything is up to its current version.
How can I keep using Sass if this extension isn't working? [Sass extension error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3tV3.png)  Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been bothering me for so bloody long... Turns out (for me anyway) it was the extension "Color Highlight" that was causing it to crash. I'm going to be very careful downloading random extensions in the future..

Comment: Wow, it's definitely this plugin. Crazy! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

for my situtation it blocks me only when I import a partial scss file so disabled it and only enable it when i have no more partial files to import.
color highlight is very useful for me.
or you can use the npm module "node-sass" with the flag -w

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact issue I'm facing currently while using the "Live Sass Compiler". Whenever I try to edit any "@import" lines it just gives me the error.
See this image ... [Extension host termination error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG37S.png)

**Problem:**
I'm facing this issue only while using the "Live Sass Compiler" as you can see in the screenshot ... [Error in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lBDu.png). This is similar to the one you're getting.

**Quick Fix:**
There must be some interruptions in the process due to which the extension is causing this error. Now, continue using the sass compiler and getting rid of that error I would suggest you uninstall the "Live Sass Compiler" and instead use `npm install node-sass --save-dev` to install the **node-sass** compiler as a dependency. Now in **package.json** enter the required script for node-sass to run.
This will allow you to compile .scss files to css. For more info checkout this link "https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass".

---

Hope you got your answer, 
Cheers!